# NSUserDefaults & bindings

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsuserdefaults, binding

How can I synchronize two interface elements and have the value saved at termination? I connected a checkbox' state and a text field's enabled to an NSObjectController. The "content" outlet is connected to the checkbox too. (Not sure why?). It works with the NSObjectController but whenever I bind the value's to an NSUserDefaultsController, my app crashes at launch with this error:

> An uncaught exception was raised
>   [
>   addObserver:
>   forKeyPath:@"selection.enabled"
>   options:0x0 context:0x0] was sent to
>   an object that is not KVC-compliant
>   for the "selection" property.
>   *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException',
>   reason: '[ addObserver:
>   forKeyPath:@"selection.enabled"
>   options:0x0 context:0x0] was sent to
>   an object that is not KVC-compliant
>   for the "selection" property.'

Answer (score 1):

`selection` comes from NSObjectController, and the NSUserDefaultsController isn't a kind of NSObjectController. You need to bind through its `values` instead.